# Get current line number in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have a contenteditable element which is being used for simple text editing. I need to get the current line number that the caret is on.

Is this possible? Here is my code for the contenteditable element.

```
<section contenteditable="true" id="writer">
    <p>write something</p>
</section>
```

Comment: I assume the text within the `<p>` can wrap?